# MSTest: No test discoverer is registered to perform discovery of test cases

Tags: mstest

I created a console application that was designed to be completely self-reliant and contain all the necessary DLLs to run. I was able to do this and get it to run locally, but when copying to another computer I began to receive this message...

**"No test discoverer is registered to perform discovery of test cases. Register a test discoverer and try again."**

I found this Microsoft bug report, but it was closed as could not reproduce:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770093/unit-test-project-not-discovering-test-cases

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to sit around waiting for Microsoft to say they couldn't reproduce so I dug into it and found that the reason I was getting this error message is because I was missing the DLL file **"Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll"**.

This is the file that contains the test discoverer and it needs to be in directory of the executable that is running the tests as well as the directory of the test files themselves. It is easy to miss because the assemblies to run the tests appear to be completely contained within the **"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform"** namespace and the tests appear to only require a reference to **"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting"**.

I decided to post this "knowledge share" post because there was no other information about the issue on the internet and Microsoft's documentation of their MSTest framework is bad at best.

Answer (score 0):

Just come across this issue with some unit tests originally written in .Net 3.5 and running (or not) in vs 2013.

The UnitTestFramework.dll mentioned by Love2Learn was present however updating to .Net 4.5 seems to resolve the problem.

I'm sure someone out there can explain why but my gut feeling is that this has something to do with this being a multi-platform solution and that .Net 4.5 is just better at running 32bit unit tests against 64bit projects.